# Static web resources in a Maven Jar?

Tags: java, maven, static-resource

Is it possible to package static resources (like Css, Js or images) in a Jar for use in a webapplication (war)?

I would like to seperate parts of the app into modules, but these don't only depend on Java classes, like controllers or models, but on views, templates and media. So I want to package all of that in a Maven module project and copy classes to the classpath and static files into any directory under the root of the application or WEB-INF.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Servlet 3.0 specification has come up with a specification JSR 315, in which you can specify web-fragments.xml and put your files(Even js, css files) under META-INF/resources folder. These files will be compiled into jar. Keep this jar in WEB-INF/lib folder. While deploying your app, container will deploy META-INF/resources files into respected location. 
Here is how structure should look like

[image: web-fragment.xml example]

```
 <web-fragment metadata-complete="true" version="3.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-fragment_3_0.xsd">
  <name>part1</name>

</web-fragment>
```

more about web fragments here : 
[Shing Wai Chan's Oracle blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/swchan/entry/servlet_3_0_web_fragment)

Comment: If there are 100+ project jars, then in which jar's web-fragment should one put the static resources?